# Return inside event completed handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm in the process of building this method which simply returns the content of a webpage. However, I can't return inside the event which is fired once the content is downloaded, getting this error:

Since 'System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

If I take the return outside of the event, it won't fire after the download is complete, returning void and therefore making this useless

```
string ScrapePage(string url)
        {
            WebClient GetArticleHTML = new WebClient();
            GetArticleHTML.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            GetArticleHTML.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, x) =>
            {
                return x.Result;
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming.

You can't return in the event because events typically return `void` in .NET. In fact, by trying to do this, you are trying to force it to be synchronous! If your code worked, by the time the event handler was invoked, `ScrapePage` would have long completed, and you would be returning the value to, well, nothing, since the function had already returned!

So you have two options:

1. Make the method synchronous (using `DownloadString` instead of the async version) and return when its done. This might not be possible since you are on WP8, which likes async methods.
2. Understand that the `ScrapePage` method simply **starts** the string download. The event handler will  need to notify whoever wants the string that it is done downloading. It can then pass the downloaded string on a method call as a parameter.

Realistically, you will want to do (2), especially if this is on the UI thread.